# Is there any command to toggle enable auto text wrapping?

Tags: vim

By default, I think my vimrc setttings enable the auto-wrapping. However, sometimes, I would like to see text lines are not wrapped. Is there any command I toggle the text line wrapping enabled and disabled? This would avoid me to exit and to change settings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
:set nowrap
```

There is also the `linebreak` option that controls whether wrapped text is broken at word boundaries or not.

Answer (score 61):

I think what you want is:

```
:set wrap!
```

This will toggle line wrapping.

More about using ! (bang) to alter commands can be found at:

```
:help :_!
```

Comment: You could use ':set wrap!' or ':set invwrap' as {option}! and inv{option} are synonymous with inverting a value, but the ! (bang) operator has functionality on top of this, as @jeremy-cantrell pointed out.

Comment: perfect. And I dont even need to write a function!

Answer (score 17):

In your vimrc, create a function such as this:

```
:function ToggleWrap()
: if (&wrap == 1)
:   set nowrap
: else
:   set wrap
: endif
:endfunction
```

Then map a key (such as F9) to call this function, like so:

```
map <F9> :call ToggleWrap()<CR>
map! <F9> ^[:call ToggleWrap()<CR>
```

Whenever you press F9, it should toggle your wrapping on and off.

Comment: I still think my method is still valid if you would prefer the convenience of toggling the word-wrap on and off with a function key (or some other keystroke), instead of typing a command.

Answer (score 6):

Add the following to have CTRL+W toggle wrapping. You can change it to some other key if you don't want `w` to be it.

```
map <C-w> :set wrap!<CR>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [quickref](http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/quickref.html) suggests (no)wrap

Answer (score 0):

I happen to like tpope’s unimpaired plugin, where `yow` will toggle wrap settings.

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to change the text instead of just visual effect, for example in git commit, just press `qt` in a roll and press enter. This will properly wrap the current paragraph your cursor is in. The paragraph is only delimited by blank lines. or you can select some area to press `qt`.

I found this by total accident.